# The regExp in javascript not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

Below is my html page and script at the bottom of the html page.

The regex thing does not seem to work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">  </p>
 <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>

 </body>
 <script>

  //below is the format obtained from the db
  var format="##,##,###";
   var reverseFormat=Array.from(format).reverse().join('');
   var reverseFormatLength=reverseFormat.length;
   //below are various separator
   var firstseparator=null;
    var restSeparator=null;
   var firstSeparatorIndicator=0;
    var indicesForVariousSeparators=[];

    var number='123456524578';
    x=number.toString();
     var stringToGoIntoTheRegex=2;

     var regex = new RegExp("\B(?=(\d{"+ stringToGoIntoTheRegex+"})+(?!\d))" , "g");

      var lastThree = x.substring(x.length-4);
      var otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-4);
       if(otherNumbers != '')
       lastThree = ',' + lastThree;


    var res = otherNumbers.replace(regex, ",") + lastThree;

     alert(res);

      </script>

      </html>
```

In above code, I am using

```
 var stringToGoIntoTheRegex=2;

 var regex = new RegExp("\B(?=(\d{"+ stringToGoIntoTheRegex+"})+(?!\d))" , "g");
```

But this does not seem to work.

Output should be 
        :1,23,45,65,24,578

Every help would be precious.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with the regex?

Comment: Just a note: *When using the constructor function, the normal string escape rules (preceding special characters with \ when included in a string) are necessary.*

Comment: @revo seems to be the root cause. That could be an answer

Comment: @Mike, stringToGoIntoTheRegex is supposed to be a number that comes from DB. It is not a special character

Comment: are you so complicated: `var last = 3, other = 2, regex = new RegExp("\\d(?=(?:\\d{"+other+"})*\\d{"+last+"}$)", "g"); console.log(x.replace(regex, "$&,"));`